# Looping cut with the same length

Tags: loop

did you guys have any trick on how to snap the **loop cut** with the same side length of the box?
what I usually did is I always do count the length of the side then calculate the value to match the length. it really frustrates me to do it over and over again. thanks :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not create the object with known units? For example, if I were to make that shape, I would start with a plane, and extrude it by 0.1  on the Z axis `(E+Z+0.1)`. I would then repeat this 3 times `(Shift+R x 3)`. Then I would add a vertical loop cut to the center and "edge slide" it by pressing `G+G+0.9` which would put it 0.1 units away from the edge - the same as the distance between the horizontal edge loops.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I think that way it's gonna work only if you have an integers value or some value that easy to remember. My point is I looking for how do I get the same length of the edge side without measuring it considering the value is not always an integer.

Comment: It can be scaled uniformly afterward. The overall size doesn't have to be in integer, but the width:length:height ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you can create  a "ruler": select the 5 vertices of the corner, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate them, move over on the Z axis, rotate them 90 degrees on X axis with pivot point on the first vertex, create 4 loop cuts, select the first with <kbd>Alt</kbd> left click, move it on Y axis with vertex snap On, pointing at the second vertex of the ruler. Do the same for the others loopcuts. Repeat until done.

[image]

Comment: this method is quite helpful, although it is not what I expected. I thought there is still a way how to adjust the length without needing a lot of steps like duplicating, moving, then moving the pivot and rotating it. where it takes like tens of seconds.
anyway, the method you gave was very helpful. so thanks for your advice. :)